# SSIS flat file output without a BOM?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package created in VS2008 that dumps a SQL Server table into a flat file.  I then try to copy that flat file into AWS Redshift and it bombs due to the flat file having a BOM in the first position.  I changed the flat file manager's code page to 65001 (UTF-8) thinking this would solve the problem, but it didn't.  How do I prevent a BOM from being added to the flat file?

Comment: Is your source data nvarchar? In your data flow, double click the connector line from your source to the flat file destination and report back what data types you see (DT_XXX)

Comment: I do/did have a DT_NTEXT field.  I added a Derived Column that converts it to a new DT_TEXT field (and the original DT_NTEXT field is not mapped to any output).

Comment: Are you really exporting something with more than 8k characters? Would a conversion to DT_STR and a length of 8000 (or less) suffice?

Comment: My bad.  The DT_NEXT to DT_TEXT conversion did the trick!  Thanks